# как можно ускорить

Tags: python, скорость

как можно ускорить этот код ?

```
def get_tid_by_index(player, index):
    for t_id in t_id_dict:
        if t_id_dict[t_id]['index'] == index:
            return t_id
    return None
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Добавьте в сам вопрос информацию о входных данных, что делает ваш код, почему необходимо ускорить, как вы замеряете скорость сейчас. Для этого нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1395870/edit) под самим вопросом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один вариант - создать обратный индекс. Т.е. создать `dict` `index_to_tid` из индексов в `t_id` и при добавлении в `t_id_dict` добавлять туда значение и его использовать при поиске:

```
t_id_dict = {}
index_to_tid = {}

def add_t(t_id, t):
   t_id_dict[t_id] = t
   index_to_tid[t_id['index']] = t_id

def get_tid_by_index(player, index):
   return index_to_tid.get(index, None)
```